# atmega32 is working OK but atmega32A is NOT!

Tags: avr, atmega, lcd, avrdude, avr-gcc

I have a board which there is an LCD on it and I want to show some lines in the LCD.
I have a broken-pin Atmega32 which the **broken pins didn't used for LCD**, I have written a simple code which just shows on and off a text in LCD.

Since my Atmega32 is broken and the broken pins are needed for another part of circuit I had to buy a new Atmega32 but all I found is Atmega32A.

Since technically Atmega32A can be used instead of ordinary Atmega32, I have compiled and burnt the same code that I have written for Atmega32 into the newly bought Atmega32A.
But **the LCD does not work anymore** and also I had a sample code which rotates a step-motor clockwise and counter-clockwise each with **1000ms** delay.
But it took **almost 5000ms** in Atmega32A in order **to change** the rotation direction.

I don't really know what is going on!!!

Can anybody help me on this?

> [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/39215/atmega32-vs-atmega32a-one-works-that-other-one-not) is a question about the same problem that I have but the accepted answer does not contain any useful detail on how to solve the problem(or atleast I don't get it!!).

### More details

[image: The LCD display on an ordinary Atmega32]
Above picture is the the LCD display on an **ordinary Atmega32**.
[image: The LCD display with same code on an Atmega32A(no output)]
Above picture is the LCD display with same code on an **Atmega32A**(no output)

The codes to compile and burn the codes:

```
#!/bin/bash
avr-gcc -mmcu=atmega32 lcd-sample-main.c -o .makefiles/lcd-sample-main  -O1 && \
avr-objcopy -O ihex .makefiles/lcd-sample-main .makefiles/lcd-sample-main.hex && \
sudo avrdude -c usbasp -p m32 -U flash:w:.makefiles/lcd-sample-main.hex
```

Comment: Have you tried pulling the firmware from the '32 to be certain that both are running the same code?

Comment: I believe this is the fuse bits problem. Fresh chip may come with different default bits.

Comment: Good call. A big chunk of port C is used by JTAG by default, and the incorrect clock source would throw off the timing for the LCD.

Comment: Use AVRDUDE to read the current fuse bytes from the '32 and then write them to the '32A. [AVRDUDE documentation](http://www.nongnu.org/avrdude/user-manual/avrdude.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was with the fuse bits setting in the new '32A controller.
Thanks to *Ignacio* for giving the idea, I read the current fuse bytes from the '32 and then wrote them to the '32A and everything is working now.

To reading the fuse bits:

```
sudo avrdude -c usbasp -p m32 -U lfuse:r:-:h -U hfuse:r:-:h
```

And for writing them(These are the values that i have read from the '32 fro `lfuse` and `hfuse`)

```
sudo avrdude -c usbasp -p m32 -U lfuse:w:0xf4:m -U hfuse:w:0xdf:m
```

Done!